# Writing Notepad++ plugin on C#. Call SCintilla with params like char *text

Tags: c#, plugins, notepad++, scintilla

I am writing a plugin for notepad++ on c#. My plugin creates a tree to represents the stucture of some specific text-files. 
I have some problems calling functions with paramets like (char* text). Could you help mw with this problem ?

for example

```
SCI_GETLINE(int line, char *text)
{
    string st="";
    Win32.SendMessage(curScintilla, SciMsg.SCI_GETLINE, (int)line, st);
}
```

such way of calling raise Not valid string format exeption.

Comment: If somebody face up to this problem, a answer it for myself. My plugin work in other thread, so i must use marshalling, to get this string.

Answer (score 2):

Tag the argument with: `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]`. The problem is you are passing a unicode string in some string type that's not an byte C-style null terminated string.

Comment: And instead of string use StringBuilder, this is how it worked for me